# Install python3.6 on Termux android terminal emulator

Tags: python, termux

I am tring to excetute a GitHub pyton script on my Android smartphon using Termux.
I knew that this script doesn't run on Python 3.8.1 (which is the default version installed when typed "pkg install python" but it runs very well on previous versions of linux. I have to mention that I know this since I was running this script on my laptop and I have different version of python installed.
However, I've looked for a couple of days in a row on google and I didn't find a way to install an older python version on my Termux. Could you please help me out on this?
Thanks in advance,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 1):

Unlike regular Linux Distributions, Termux does not keep a history of the version updates hence installing Python 3.6 is a difficult task, but it's not impossible, you'll have to build and install python from its source code. Which you can find (for version 3.6.10) here : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3610/

And if you need help with installation, I'd ask you to follow the guide here without the *sudo* commands. (https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-python-source/)

Answer (score 0):

`pkg i python==[version]`
you specify the version you want just after the package name. That is
`pkg i python==3.6 -y`

considering 3.6 is the version then the `-y` simply means yes

Answer (score 0):

its actually `pkg i python=3.6` and termux don't have that python version