# How to use python module in termux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, module, termux

How can I install python module in our android linux environment Termux. If you anyone have Idea about this topic let me know

I think I can solve my problem from here

Comment: I suggest adding what Python version you need installed and the version of Termux you are working with. After that, see if [this article](https://www.crisisshelter.org/install-python2-and-python3-in-termux/) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921715/install-python3-6-on-termux-android-terminal-emulator) and its answers help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `pkg install python` to install python then verify with `python --version`. If you want a specific python version use `pkg search python` and verify if your desired version is available. then `pkg install python3.9` by example, to install python3.9.

With python installed you can install your modules or packages using pip like this: `pip install your_module_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I draw your attention to the fact that now the `pip` command is presented separately from the `python` package in [termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/13397). This means that in order to work with python modules, you need to install the `python-pip` package.

```
pkg upg
pkg ins python
pkg ins python-pip # Installed modules will remain
```

**Note**: this is for python3 only and updating pip via pip is disabled here (https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/pull/13611#issuecomment-1336105506).

Answer (score -1):

**USE THIS COMMAND:**

**pkg install python**
**pkg install python2**
**pkg install python3**